# Is there a way to force a method to use a subclass constructor without using instanceof?

Tags: java

Sorry if my formating is not good, first time on StackOverflow.
I have a FruitBuilder class for a set of objects of the same type that are all extensions of the Fruit class, the FruitBuilder contains a set of variables that look like this:

```
public Apple redApple = new Apple(size, color, price);
public Orange bigOrange = new Orange(size, color, price);
public Pear greenPear = new Pear(size, color, price);
```

and I have a copy method called makeFruit that creates a new fruit and adds it to an ArrayList fruits and looks like this:

```
public Fruit makeFruit(Fruit f){
    Fruit fruit = new Fruit(f.size, f.color, f.price);
    fruits.add(fruit);
    return fruit;
}
```

This works fine except that it creates a new Fruit instead of the required Subclass, I could make it work by using a series of instanceof checks and then forcing the Subclass in a case by case basis:

```
public Fruit makeFruit(Fruit f){    
 if (f instanceof Apple){
        Apple apple = new Apple(f.size, f.color, f.price);
        fruits.add(apple);
        return apple;
        //snip
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: You appear to be using a class as a type where you could have an attribute like `enum Type { Apple, Orange, Pear }` and just have a field for this and only one `Fruit` class.

Comment: That's because each subclass has different methods that override the superclass.

Comment: I suspect they can be attribute based as well.

Comment: Do *all* your methods override a superclass method in your concrete classes? Because if you don't have any unique methods in your concrete classes, you should use an `enum` like @Peter suggested.

Comment: Yes, each subclass is around 200 lines of code on a 1000 lines main class, I only used Fruits as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an abstract method in the Fruit class

```
public abstract Fruit copy()
```

And then add a concrete implementation in each of your subclasses, e.g. for the Apple class:

```
@Override
public Apple copy(){
    Apple apple = new Apple(this.size, this.color, this.price);
    fruits.add(apple);
    return apple;
}
```

Comment: Why make it take the `Fruit` that you're copying? You could just have a `copy()` method with no args so you can just do `fruits.add(apple.copy())`. It is, after all, an instance method in your example.

Comment: A valid point. If it was a class method the argument would be needed, in this example it would be better to just copy the instance values. I'll update the example.

Comment: This would probably work for me, sounds like the best solution to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, and thanks to Brian for the improvements

Comment: It just occured to me, shouldn't the abstract method end with ; or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You are correct, the example was typed without the use of an IDE ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) -- it is designed for exactly this purpose:

```
public Fruit makeFruit(Fruit f) {
    Fruit fruit = (Fruit)f.clone();
    fruits.add(fruit);
    return fruit;
}
```

There are several ways to make `clone()` work for your classes. The easiest is to make `Fruit` implement [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html):

```
public class Fruit implements Cloneable {
    ...
}
```

It is a [marker interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern), so you won't need to implement any methods.

Comment: No sorry, I forgot to mention I need a shallow copy not a deep copy, clone is no go. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: `clone()` returns `Object`, you need to cast it.

Comment: Clone is not deep copy, it has several flaw.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reflection:

```
public Fruit makeFruit(Fruit f)
{
    Fruit fruit = f.getClass()
                   .getConstructor(int.class, int.class, int.class)
                   .newInstance(f.size, f.color, f.price);
    fruits.add(fruit);
    return fruit;
}
```

You need to handle the exceptions.

Comment: Sounds pretty good, I'll probably use the copy() method suggested in another answer so I don't have to deal with different constructors but I'll keep this in mind for the future. Thank you.